# why doesn't this ERB standalone rendering work for the instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

why doesn't this ERB standalone rendering work for the instance variable?  That is the output is blank for the "<%= @test_var %>" line?

```
@test_var = "test variable"
template = Tilt.new('./app/scripts/email.erb')
st = template.render
puts st
```

and email.erb

```
<html>
<body>
  <h1>This is it!</h1>
  <p>
      Phone Number: <%= @test_var %>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

gives

```
<html>
<body>
  <h1>This is it!</h1>
  <p>
   Phone Number:
  </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the answer...need to have

(a) the following in my class where the instance variables are:

```
  # Support templating of member data.
  def get_binding
    binding
  end
```

(b) also when calling "run" on the ERB object have to pass the result from this method, e.g.

```
rhtml = ERB.new(erb_str)
html = rhtml.run(get_binding)
```

Comment: worked for me, you can also omit the function get_binding and pass binding directly.  I wanted to get the string as html so i did `html = rhtml.result(binding)`

Answer (score 1):

Was just working on something similar today. This is how I got it to work:

```
template = File.read("path/to/template.html.erb").gsub(/^  /, '')
rhtml = ERB.new(template)
@hash_of_all_i_need_in_template = method_to_get_hash_of_all_i_need_in_template
email_contents = rhtml.result(Proc.new{@hash_of_all_i_need_in_template})
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
test_var = "test variable"
template = Tilt.new('./app/scripts/email.erb')
st = template.render(self, test_var: test_var)
puts st
```

and

```
<html>
<body>
  <h1>This is it!</h1>
  <p>
      Phone Number: <%= test_var %>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this didn't work actually - it gave " `evaluate_source': undefined local variable or method `test_var' for "test variable":String (NameError)"

Comment: fix:
st = template.render(self,test_var:test_var)

Comment: thanks @kp666. I didn't test that but it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the binding context to the template, your code should be

```
@test_var = "test variable"
template = Tilt.new('./app/scripts/email.erb')
st = template.render(self)
puts st
```